# React Carbon Modal Positioning

Tags: css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm using the React-Carbon library to design a new part of a frontend for a client, and I'm having problems with the positioning of a modal. As you can see in the image below, clicking on the button in the table opens the modal (and makes the 'darkening' div visible), but the position of the modal isn't relative to where the viewer is currently looking. As a result, it looks as if the modal hasn't opened until you scroll up.

[image: Modal for rows at top of table, and bottom]

The CSS for the modal is as follows:

```
.bx--modal {
align-items: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
height: 920px;
justify-content: center;
left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
visibility: hidden;
width: 1680px;
z-index: 9000;
}
```

EDIT, the HTML is as follows:

```html
<div role="dialog" class="bx--modal-container" aria-label="Edit requisition" aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1"><div class="bx--modal-header"><h3 id="bx--modal-header__heading--modal-125" class="bx--modal-header__heading">Settings</h3><button class="bx--modal-close" type="button" title="Close" aria-label="Close"><svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" aria-label="Close" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 32 32" role="img" class="bx--modal-close__icon"><path d="M24 9.4L22.6 8 16 14.6 9.4 8 8 9.4 14.6 16 8 22.6 9.4 24 16 17.4 22.6 24 24 22.6 17.4 16 24 9.4z"></path></svg></button></div><div id="bx--modal-body--modal-125" class="bx--modal-content" aria-labelledby="bx--modal-header__heading--modal-125"><svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="currentColor" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true" class="bx--select__arrow"><path d="M8 11L3 6 3.7 5.3 8 9.6 12.3 5.3 13 6z"></path></svg></div></div></div></div></div><div class="bx--modal-footer bx--btn-set"><button tabindex="0" class="bx--btn bx--btn--secondary" type="button">Cancel</button><button tabindex="0" class="bx--btn bx--btn--primary" type="button">Save</button></div></div>
```

Comment: Can you share the respective HTML/JSX for the modal?

Comment: try with `height: 100vh;` inestead of  `height: 920px;`

Comment: Could be some other CSS conflicting with the modal. If you render the modal element somewhere higher up the component tree (e.g. in your root component) with a [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), does it work?

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal Certainly. The JSX is the default React Carbon modal the HTML is above now.

Comment: @RohitVerma - Thanks, I tried that, but nothing. I've checked, and all of the sizes are relative, but Chrome just converted them to absolutes when I copied.

Comment: @cbr I will try that now, thanks!

Comment: @cbr - this solved it! If you'd like to make it a proper answer, I'll happily mark it correct for future users :)

Comment: @RichardCoates Well, it's more of a debug step :) You can answer your own question, I'd love to see what the conflicting CSS was.

Comment: Me too, but there are SO many layers in this SPA that it would take a long time to go through them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you render the modal into a separate div using React.createPortal (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), you should be able to use the default Carbon modal CSS.

Here is an example codepen: jGBWpE.

H/T to user cbr who suggested this debugging step.